# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package - when import file

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, module, package

python 3.7.7 and also tried on python 3.6.0

I am using **Django** server, and in my **views.py**

I am trying to get my function that in the **detector**.

By file when I try to import my detector file:

```
from ..DataFromSkyDetector import Detector
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

it's raised this error:

ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

I am adding a picture of the hierarchy,

I already added all the routes **init**.py.

i, I made my detector file as a package and return it to a file,

I read every stackoverflow question that regarded to this problem.

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
del sys.path[0]
sys.path.insert(0,'Datafromskydetector file address ')
 import DataFromSkyDetector
```

or look up this [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6ve1ie/attempted_relative_import_beyond_toplevel_package/) and [valueeroor](https://napuzba.com/a/relative-import-beyond-top-level-package) for some help.